# jQuery variable with 0 (zero) value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that I past to a function called `comment_test` that will sometimes be `0`, but it fails because I guess it reads it as `false`. I get the error `'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: count'`.

But, I need to know if the variable is indeed `0` (and not `1`, `2`, `3`, etc). The function works fine with any positive number. How is this achieved or what am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find any info on this.

```
var test = comment_test(0, true);
```

Comment: We need more code then what you provided, please post the declaration for `comment_test`

Comment: Why would you not provide us with the code of `comment_test`?  Are we supposed to figure that out to help you?  Do we get double the rep from upvotes if we do?

Comment: Hey sorry for not posting more code. I figured this was a more general question about using 0, and not code specific - Im experimenting with what Libert Piou Piou posted below. Failing that I'll post the code Im having the issue with. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the strict comparison :

```
var myVar = 0;
myVar === 0;//returns true
myVar === false;//returns false
```

Comment: The strict comparisons worked in my case - thanks!